# Different autofill in system in subsite

Tags: html, autocomplete

I am writing a web system on a certain domain with a log-in dialog.

The system lies on an address

```
http://www.example.com/systemB/
```

However, there is a different system at address

```
http://www.example.com/systemA/
```

that uses a different log-in dialog, with different credentials. (Users who use `systemB` often use `systemA` too.)

Most browsers, however, automatically take the credentials from `http://www.example.com/systemA/` and auto-fill them in the  `http://www.example.com/systemB/`.

Can I write the website in such a way, that the dialog won't be autofilled from the `systemA` automatically, but the auto-fill will still be allowed? (For example, write some "auto-fill domain".)

I know I can ues `autocomplete="off"`, but I don't want to turn it off outright.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly does autocomplete in browsers work, but have you tried changing the names of the input elements?

Comment: Yes. At least Chrome is pretty clever when searching for login input elements, and it immediately uses the ones from systemA

Answer (score 1):

You can try set empty value to the fields from systemA (value=""). When the user open it, the fields are empty but if he click on them, there will be autofill recommendations.